how to trigger dbt to create model based on WARN of fail
I have a marco detects if a test has warning. warning is about relationship check. the logic is if there is a warning, run another model.
{% macro check_test_results() %}
  {% for result in results %}
    {% if result.status in ["warn", "fail"] %}
      {% if result.node.unique_id.startswith("test.prj_dbt.relationships_sch__fact_table_CUSTOMER_CODE__CUSTOMER_CODE__ref_sch___dim_customer_")
         or result.node.unique_id.startswith("test.prj_dbt.relationships_sch__fact_table_CUSTOMER_CODE__CUSTOMER_CODE__ref_sch___dim_product_") %}
        {{ log("Running exception query due to test failure: " ~ result.node.unique_id, info=True) }}
        
        -- Include your SQL directly here
        {% do run_query(
            " 
              select
                  f.*
              from mytable.FACT_SELLOUT f
              left join mytable.DIM_CUSTOMER c
              on f.CUSTOMER_CODE = c.CUSTOMER_CODE
              where c.CUSTOMER_CODE is null
            "
        ) %}
        
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

but i get this error and SQL faild to run. and also I prefer it to execute another sql file instead of hard coded sql statement if possible.
 Encountered an error:
local variable 'connection' referenced before assignment


Could you share how you invoke this macro?

i invoked it by add on-run-end hook in the dbt_project.yml
on-run-end: "{{ check_test_results() }}"

The results variable available inside of the on-run-end hook context only (see details here). It's a significant dbt anti-pattern to run DDL operations (such as create table) outside of run, seed, snapshot operations.
You should probably redesign your dbt models to achieve the desired behavior.
Most probably, you can do the the relationship check inside your model using SQL and joins and handle the output with CTE.
It's hard to tell more without more details.
